# JavaFX - Stretching and filling Pane with multiple components

Tags: layout, javafx, fxml, autofill

### Here's what I'm trying to achieve :

[image]

### Here's where I am at :

[image]

### This is my layout :

[image]

I can't figure out how to nest my components so that the ViewList fills all the remaining space ( considering that the Label takes a portion of that Pane ).

I'm asking not only for this particular case, but also in general when I want to fit multiple components in a container. Some components have fixed height/width and some have to fill the remaining space. Is there a strategy or dedicated container for that ?

Ex :

[image]
*correction : Filling-remaining-space component(s)*

Most of the time I just ( thanks god there is something like scene builder ) spam all the options until I figure out how things seem to work.

I also looked at Vgrow and Hgrow properties but it dosen't seem to always work ( or maybe I'm using it the wrong way ).

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set `vGrow` for the `SplitPane` that contains panes:

```
 VBox.setVgrow(centerSplitPane, Priority.ALWAYS);
```